# Building OpenSSL 1.0.2 on iOS - make depend fails

Tags: ios, openssl

I am trying to build OpenSSL 1.0.2 for iOS, but I am getting an error with `make depend`. Here is the terminal output:

```
$ ./Configure iphoneos-cross no-shared no-dso no-hw no-engine --prefix=/usr/local/openssl-ios

...

Since you've disabled or enabled at least one algorithm, you need to do
the following before building:

    make depend

Configured for iphoneos-cross.
$ make depend
making depend in crypto...
makedepend: error:  failed to read /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk
mv: Makefile.new: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [depend] Error 1
```

The directory it is complaining about exists and has read right for everyone, so I am at a loss on what to do. I tried to `sudo` it (against my better judgement) but that only resulted in a toooonnn more "No such this or that" errors.

Is there a step I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to configure here, and gave a very similar error. What solved for me:

- Download Xcode version 11.7 and 12.5;
- Keep in Xcode>preferences>locations>command line tools version 12.5;
- Rename the file from Xcode version 12.5 to only Xcode and 11.7 to Xcode_old
- Run again!

I hope it works for you too!